# Get response body

Tags: html, vb.net, mpeg

I'am currenty using code :

```
Private Function getHtmlres(ByVal response As HttpWebResponse) As String
    Dim myWebSource As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim myPageSource As String = String.Empty
    myPageSource = myWebSource.ReadToEnd()
    Return myPageSource
End Function
```

But the problem is that I'm downloading audio/mpeg object. When I see the

```
MsgBox(getHtmlres(myHttpWebResponse1))
```

It shows :

```
ID3<<<SQUARE>>>
```

. When I do

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\sdg.txt",getHtmlres(myHttpWebResponse1))
```

it writes 0 bytes.

Comment: You need to rewind the stream and stop treating binary data as strings. :)

Comment: Why are you passing streams around as strings? Just use streams directly.